# delete first apperance of slash inside link

Tags: regex, unix, terminal

There are set of HTML files I have inside directory. I made a mistake by starting all of the links (href attribute) with "/" (e.g. /news.html, /images/img1.jpg, etc.). How can I change this inside all of the files using RegEx and UNIX command line. I run latest version of Mac OS.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
sed -i '.sav' 's/href="\//href="/g' *.html
```

It will replace in-place each `href=/` with `href=` in all files with `.html` extension, saving the original file with `.sav` extension.